# Removing charaters from string in a list of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list,  `lst =[['ABC, CN', 'X'], ['DCS, BA', 'X'], ['SCS, TW', 'X'], ['SFA, GW', 'X']]`. Want to remove the last 4 charaters in the in the first part of ever string? Is this possible?

Wanted outcome would be:

`newlist = [['ABC', 'X'], ['DCS', 'X'], ['SCS', 'X'], ['SFA', 'X']]`

I've tried:

```
newlist= [sub[:][: -1] for sub in list]
```

But this gives me:

```
newlist = [['ABC'], ['DCS'], ['SCS'], ['SFA']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unpacking when iterate over elements of the list.

```
>>> [[a[:-4], b] for (a, b) in lst]
[['ABC', 'X'], ['DCS', 'X'], ['SCS', 'X'], ['SFA', 'X']]
```